# How to fix deprecated substring(with: )

Tags: swift, substring

I'm working through a book exercise where the author has the following code.

```
func getMatchingString(str: String) -> String? {
    if let newMatch = str.range(of:regExFindMatchString,                          
                 options:.regularExpression) {
        return str.substring(with: newMatch)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

the str.substring(with: newMatch) line shows 'substring(with:) is deprecated use String slicing subscript.'

I've tried to figure out what to use to fix this but everything I've tried shows I just don't understand this well enough to fix it.  I know that the newMatch is a range object, just can't figure out how to use it effectively.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Bob

Comment: `return str.substring(with: newMatch)` => `return String(str[newMatch])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use subscripting with the range you obtain from the `if let`

```
if let newMatchRange = str.range(of:regExFindMatchString,   options:.regularExpression) {
    return String(str[newMatchRange])
} else {
    return nil
}
```

You need to translate it to a String as the method actually returns a Substring type, not a String.

Comment: Thank you, I've written code for 40 years in various languages, but Swift's power has me flummoxed.  I picked up Java much more intuitively than this.... but I love this language...